# Preferred method for viewing code generated by Template Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghc, pretty-print, template-haskell

As you know, Template Haskell is used to generate various kinds of AST splices programmatically at compile-time.

However, a splice can often be very opaque, and it is often difficult to discern what a splice actually generates. If you run the `Q` monad for a splice, and the splice is well-typed, you get a `show`able representation of the generated piece of AST, but this representation can be very difficult to understand, because of its unstructured layout.

What is the preferred method for converting a piece of TH-generated AST into something akin to normal Haskell code, so that the code can be easily read and understood? Can one reconstruct source code from e.g. a given `Dec` value? Does one have to read the GHC Core code? Is there a way to at least structure the AST so that it becomes more readable (Beyond what e.g. the `pretty-show` package does)?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You may be able to use `pprint` or `ppr` from [Language.Haskell.TH.Ppr](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/template-haskell/latest/doc/html/Language-Haskell-TH-Ppr.html) (imported automatically with [Language.Haskell.TH](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/template-haskell/latest/doc/html/Language-Haskell-TH.html)):

```
GHCi> expr <- runQ [| \f g x -> f (x*2 + 3) . g |]
GHCi> putStrLn $ pprint expr
\f_0 g_1 x_2 -> f_0 ((x_2 GHC.Num.* 2) GHC.Num.+ 3) GHC.Base.. g_1
```

It's not pretty, but it *is* valid Haskell. You should be able to make the output nicer by stripping off module prefixes from Prelude names (although you might need to be careful to only strip the expected prefix; `Foo.*` is a perfectly valid infix operator, after all).

Comment: This solves the part of the question that @augustss didn't answer.

Answer (score 58):

Are you looking for the `-ddump-splices` flag to the compiler?

Comment: Yes, this kind of output is precisely what I'm looking for! But can this be done in a program too given only a syntax tree, or does it require the invocation of the compiler?

Comment: note: make sure you remove .hi and .o files to get a clean build before you run this, or you won't get any stderr output.

Answer (score 1):

As a complement to [ehird answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8521839):

Note that using `runQ` directly from GHCi
in general might not work
(e.g.: TH generators that use `reify` operations,
cf. [comments above the runQ declaration](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.10.0.0/docs/src/Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax.html#runQ)).

When that fails, you can `pprint` (or `show`), transform intro a string expression `stringE` then splice as an argument to `putStrLn`:

```
> putStrLn $(stringE . pprint =<< [| \f g x -> f (x*2 + 3) . g |])
\f_0 g_1 x_2 -> f_0 ((x_2 GHC.Num.* 2) GHC.Num.+ 3) GHC.Base.. g_1
```