# View code generated by deriveJSON in Aeson

Tags: json, haskell

I'm using Aeson to parse a JSON file in Haskell, and I'm letting Aeson auto-generate the parser by calling deriveJSON. Is there any way to view the code that Aeson generates? I tried calling deriveJSON at the command line, but the result from that function doesn't derive Show, so it won't print. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass `-ddump-splices` to the compiler when compiling your code, which will output the generated parser code to the terminal. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8520170/230461) that I asked a while ago for more information.