# Generate final code from Template Haskell code

Tags: templates, haskell, compilation, compile-time, template-haskell

**Problem**

Is it possible to generate "pure" Haskell code out of the one including Template Haskell functions?

I want to get the code where all Haskell Template's qutations and splices are expanded? (to feed it into another Haskell compiler (Haste), which does not support Template Haskell yet.)

**Example**

module TupleReplicate:

```
tupleReplicate n = do 
    id <- newName "x"
    return $ LamE ([VarP id]) (TupE $ replicate n $ VarE id)
```

main:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    print $(tupleReplicate 3) "x"
    return ()
```

can be expanded to:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    print (\x->(x,x,x)) "x"
    return ()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution using Template Haskell pretty printer can be found here:
[Preferred method for viewing code generated by Template Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520170/preferred-method-for-viewing-code-generated-by-template-haskell)

There are also other tools, as answered to a question here:
[How to create a non-TH package from code generated using Template Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621582/how-to-create-a-non-th-package-from-code-generated-using-template-haskell?rq=1)

The result of `-ddump-splices` is not always valid haskell code, it is only for the programmer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to compile (or interpret in GHCi) with `-ddump-splices`.

Comment: As far as I know `-ddump-splices` does NOT generate working Haskell code.